# hide xAxes labels from Bar chart with 'react-chartjs-2'

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I have built a graph of bar chart with some data.
the current result I have is:
[image]

and what I want is to delete the names below the xAxes in the bar chart.
I viewed the react-chartjs-2 documentation and tried to change the options, also viewed Chart.Js documentation.

this is my options right now:

```
const options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    xAxes: [
      {
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false,
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: @Keith Undeleted it.
I thought it was completly impossible so deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a deep search I found the solution:

```
const options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [
      {
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
        },
      },
    ],
    xAxes: {
      ticks: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
  },
```

The problem is in xAxes it was a list instead of object.

after the fix, this is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This way you can hide it.

```
 const options = {
    indexAxis: 'y' as const,
    elements: {
        bar: {
            borderWidth: 0,
        },
    },
    scales: {
    x: {
        display: false
    },
       y: {
        display: false
    }
}
}
```

[image]